# npm se demora y se cuelga instalando dependencias

Tags: nodejs, npm

tengo un problema reciente con npm, de un dia para otro ya no puedo instalar dependencias en proyectos, al tratar de instalar se cuelga y me da este error:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@apollo%2fserver failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1323:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-28T15_21_51_561Z-debug-0.log
```

No estoy usando ningun proxy ya he intentado usar estas soluciones:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Resetear el cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Agregar estas carpetas a la lista de exclusiones de windows defender:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Y hasta desinstalé e instalé de nuevo node, pero nada me ha funcionado. Alguna solución?

PD, tampoco puedo hacerle ping a registry.npmjs.org:

```
ping registry.npmjs.org

Haciendo ping a registry.npmjs.org [2606:4700::6810:1923] con 32 bytes de datos:
Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.
Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.

Estadísticas de ping para 2606:4700::6810:1923:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 0, perdidos = 4
    (100% perdidos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que también tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione deshabilitando IPv6, te dejo el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215796/error-on-installing-node-npm-err-code-etimedout) de la respuesta a ver si eso te funciona.
Yo estoy usando Windows 11